# debugging Stored Procedure on HANA

Tags: debugging, stored-procedures, configuration, hana

I try to debug a stored procedure on HANA but I got this error:

> Procedure is not active or does not exist on the Server.

All permissions and authorization object are already assign to my user. Here what I did:

- I create  a procedure in my package on SAP HANA Development perspective view
- the procedure is active without error
- I go to Repositories and open the procedure by double click on the procedure
- I do right mouse click on the HANA Editor and choose Debug as --> SAP HANA Stored Procedure

and then I got the above error.

What is the Problem? did I do something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Did you check https://blogs.sap.com/2015/10/22/how-to-debug-abap-managed-database-procedures-using-adt-basics/ ?

Comment: the blog has nothing to do with my question. but thanks anyway for the hint

Answer (score 0):

to debug a stored procedure on HANA you have to do the following:

- search your procedure in Schema _SYS_BIC
- double click on the procedure
- toggle breakpoint
- go and create a debug configuration
- start debugging

Comment: Is this valid after a certain release? And do I need a certain role for that?